# How to match the result with the return statement of an action returning an object in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

i have an action searchUser, for that i made a method getUserById which returns the searched object.

```
    public Employee getUserById(int userId) {

    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.
                prepareStatement("select * from employee where first=? OR last=?");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, employee.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, employee.getLastName());
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            employee.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            employee.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
            employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("first"));
            employee.setLastName(rs.getString("last"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return employee;
}
```

now, what should be the matching term for result in struts.xml
because normally we match success string. but dnt know how i can match an object. Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An Action method always return a String, like SUCCESS, ERROR, INPUT, NONE, etc...;
2. your is not an Action method, it is a standard one, hence it doesn't need to be mapped in struts.xml file;

That said, it is not clear what are you trying to achieve: the standard way would be using a private `Employee` object, with Getter and Setter, and populating it from an Action method (let's say, `execute()`), then accessing it from the JSP by its name; the `userId` parameter itself should be a private variable with Getter and Setter, when coming from a POST/GET or from a redirect.

If instead you are calling it directly from a JSP tag, simply use it.

Note that there are several ways to avoid loading it multiple times, for example by pushing it on top of the Stack:

```
<s:push value="getUserById(1337)">
    <s:propery value="firstName" />
    <s:propery value="lastName" />
</s:push>
```

BTW I ***strongly*** suggest to read documentation / tutorials / examples before playing with the framework. Most of the things are already there, out-of-the-box, waiting to be discovered and used properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ModelDriven design described [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/model-driven.html). Basically you still return `String` from `execute` but also you introduce an additional method to obtain your object:

```
public class ModelDrivenAction implements ModelDriven { 
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Object getModel() {
        return new Gangster();
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is still there , coz if i need to call getModel() , then what?